Azure DevOps append commit message when branch name different than refs/tags
I try to create Azure DevOps pipeline and i want to append commit message to each pipeline run that is not executed from tags.
Start of my code looks like this:
name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false

And that does a trick:

The problem is, that when its executed on tag i dont want to append commit message but any other branch, i want to. I try to code it like that:
name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
appendCommitMessageToRunName: $(appendCommitMessageToRunName)

variables:
- name: appendCommitMessageToRunName
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/') }}:
    value: false
  ${{ if not(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')) }}:
    value: true

But unfortunately, it does not work.
So how to append commit message based on source branch name?

Interesting. What you want is to programmatically disable the appendCommitMessageToRunName parameter or to set the name parameter to the $(Build.SourceBranchName) + $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) as a compile-time expression or variable. Unfortunately, appendCommitMessageToRunName does not support compile-time expressions, and the $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) variable is unavailable at compile-time. It's as though Microsoft didn't want you to do this :-)
Fortunately, there is a workaround that would allow you to modify the build name programmatically at runtime using a logging command. However, there are some constraints:

the build number cannot be more than 255 characters
it cannot contain any of these characters: ", /, :, <, >, \, |, ?, @, or *.

The following could be used to programmatically adjust the build name at runtime:
name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false

steps:
# adjust your build name at runtime to include $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)
- ${{ if not(startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags')) }}:
  - pwsh: |

      # concat message
      $message = "$(Build.SourceBranchName) - $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"

      # replace illegal characters
      $message = $message -replace '[\"/:\<>\\\|\?\@\*]', '_'

      # remove trailing '.'
      $message = $message.TrimEnd('.')

      # trim message length
      if ($message.Length > 255)
      {
         $message = $message.Substring(0,255)
      }

      # Use logging command to update build
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updateBuildNumber]$message"
    displayName: 'Adjust Build Name'

# other steps
- ...

As this is a runtime change, the build name will start without the commit message until the step executes.
Note this operation doesn't work in the reverse: If the appendCommitMessageToRunName is set to true the message will always appear even if the build number logging command is used.
